# How Can I Filter the data using Search Field

Tags: reactjs

I Have an Search Field Input , Through that Input I need to filter the data. 
So, How Can I Filter the data using Search Field..
Can Anyone help me in this..

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor() {
   super ();
   this.state = {
     monsters : [],
     searchFeild :'',
   };
 }

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(response => response.json())
   .then(users => this.setState({monsters : users}))
}

inputData =(event)=>{
  console.log(event.target.value);
this.setState({searchFeild : event.target.value});

}

  render() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type ="text" placeholder ="Typeo" onChange={this.inputData}/>
      <CardList  monsters ={this.state.monsters}/>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

use the filter function on the monsters

```
      monsters.filter(m => !searchfield || m.name.contains(searchfield))
```

also your input is missing value. Check here for more info
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of your search is all up to you and how your monsters data-set looks. Let's say your array of monsters looks something like this:

```
monsters = [{name: "Pikachu"}, {name: "Meowth"}, {name: "Charmander"}]
```

You could do a very simple search to check whether the `string` you enter in the input is included in the `name` of the monster. It would be as simple as using `array.protoype.filter()` and `string.prototype.includes()` or `string.prototype.contains()`

Enhance your change-handler to:

```
inputData = (event) => {
   const { value } = event.target
   const { monsters } = this.state

   const filteredMonsters = monsters.filter((monster) => {
      return monster.name.includes(value)
   })

   this.setState({
      monsters: filteredMonsters
   })
}
```

But again, this is a very primitive search, you could enhance it by accounting for letter-casing, spaces, Regex and etc.